# Removing a child from the stage with active event listeners

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an `enemy` object that fires `missile` objects, like so;

```
public function fire():void {
            var missile:Bullet = new Bullet();
            stage.addChild(missile);
        }
```

No problem there.

Now, when any missile objects leave the stage area, I want to remove them. Seems simple enough. So in my `Bullet` class, I've done the following;

I've used the standard method of calling this in my constructor;

```
if (stage) init();
else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
```

Which then triggers `init();`

```
public function init(e:Event = null):void {
            trace("init");              
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, actions);
        }
```

So `actions();` is triggered by Event.ENTER_FRAME;

```
public function actions(e:Event):void {
                this.move();
                trace(stage.stageWidth); // this works fine
                stage.removeChild(this); // this throws Error #1009:
            }
```

I'm just using this is an example. My `actions();` function will eventually contain code to remove the object when it leaves the stage, not just when the function is called. I can `trace` the `stageWidth` property, no problem. So why is `stage.removeChild(this);` throwing this error?

> [Fault] exception, information=TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a
>   property or method of a null object reference.

Now, this is where it gets really baffling.

If I move `stage.removeChild(this);` into `init();`, it works perfectly. So why would it work there, and not in `actions();` which is always called *after* `init();`?

Answer (score 0):

I never thought to check for this, as I assumed once an object was removed from the stage, all of its event listeners would be as well.

Removing a child from the stage, however, does not mean the object has been deleted, so `stage.removeChild(this);` *was* working within `actions();`, but even though I'd removed the `bullet` object from the stage, it was still calling `actions();`, which was then calling `stage.removeChild(this);` again, which was trying to reference the object when it no longer existed on the stage.

```
if (this.y > stage.stageHeight) {
                stage.removeChild(this);
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, actions);
            }
```

All I had to do was remove the event listener so `actions();` would stop being called after I removed the `bullet` object from the stage.

Hopefully someone else can learn from my mistake, here. Still, I'm a bit surprised that `Event.ENTER_FRAME` still triggers even when you remove the child from the stage.